# Dirac's comments on conservation of matter from the Einstein field equations

Tags: general-relativity, energy-conservation

In Dirac's "General Theory of Relativity", at the end of Ch. 25 (p. 47), right after deriving the full Einstein equation $R^{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}R = -8\pi\rho v^\mu v^\nu = -8\pi T^{\mu\nu}$, he makes a reference to the conservation of mass (Eq. 25.3):
$$0 = (\rho v^\mu)_{:\mu} = \rho_{:\mu}v^\mu + \rho v^\mu_{\,\,:\mu}.$$

(Here $v^\mu \equiv dx^\mu/ds$.) This can be deduced from the Einstein field equation by application of the Bianci relation, but that's not important here. He then writes (this is just the chain rule, since $\rho$ is a scalar, hence $\rho_{:\mu}=\rho_{,\mu}$):
$$\frac{d\rho}{ds} = \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x^\mu} v^\mu = -\rho v^\mu_{\,\,:\mu}.$$

So far, so good. What I fail to understand is Dirac's comment that follows:

***"This is a condition that fixes how $\rho$ varies along the world line of an element of matter. It allows $\rho$ to vary arbitrarily from the world line of one element to that of a neighboring element. Thus we may take $\rho$ to vanish except for a packet of world lines forming a tube in space-time. Such a packet would compose a particle of matter of a finite size. Outside the particle we have $\rho=0$, and Einstein's field equation for empty space hold."***

Can someone interpret this? The matter density $\rho(x^\mu)$ is whatever it is; I don't see how we are free to change this. It is true that the previous equation means that you can look at an infinitesimal particle of matter, and as its proper time advances by $ds$ the previous equation gives a condition for the change $d\rho$ in matter density. However, I don't follow the comment *"It allows $\rho$ to vary arbitrarily from the world line of one element to that of a neighboring element. Thus we may take $\rho$ to vanish except for a packet of world lines forming a tube in space-time."* I'm just lost here.

Appreciate if someone could clarify this.

Comment: Dirac is stating that the conservation equation can be used to express how matter density varies from one point to other in the same trajectory. So there is a freedom to choose how this density will vary between different trajectories.

Comment: @KP99 I don't see how $\rho$ is free to be chosen. Einstein's 10 field equations involve $T^{\mu\nu}$. Presumably a particular solution depends upon some initial conditions that you can choose for $T^{\mu\nu}=\rho v^\mu v^\nu$, but thereafter the matter density/flow will be whatever it is.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. EFE only provide the local conservation law of matter-field. But to comment about the whole dynamics, you will need a seperate equation of motion for the matter-field. So if we just use EFE, there is an arbitrariness. Dirac is only assuming the form of $\rho$, which is normal: we usually calculate the metric for a given distribution